# I want to know what is the error in this lexical analysis code

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub, rxdart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:validated/validated.dart';

enum Token  {Identifier, Constant, Operator, Keyword, Error}
void main() async {
  var f = new File('data.txt');
  var fdata ;
  if(await f.exists()){
    fdata= await f.readAsString();
  }
  bool isCharacter(var str){
    if(str=='a' || str=='A'||str=='b' || str=='B'||str=='c' || str=='C'||str=='d' || str=='D'||str=='e' || str=='E'||str=='f' || str=='F'
        ||str=='g' || str=='G'||str=='h' || str=='H'||str=='i' || str=='I'||str=='j' || str=='J'||str=='k' || str=='K'||str=='l' || str=='L'
        ||str=='m' || str=='M'||str=='o' || str=='O'||str=='p' || str=='P'||str=='q' || str=='Q'||str=='r' || str=='R'||str=='s' || str=='S'
        ||str=='t' || str=='T'||str=='u' || str=='U'||str=='v' || str=='V'||str=='w' || str=='W'||str=='x' || str=='X'||str=='y' || str=='Y'
        ||str=='z' || str=='Z')
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  bool isNumber(String str)                         //check if the given substring is a number or not
  {
    int i, len = str.length, numOfDecimal = 0;
    if (len == 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if ((numOfDecimal >= 0 && str[i] == '.') || (str[i] == '.' && numOfDecimal >= 0)) //numOfDecimal > 1 this means it must pass on number 1
          {
        return true;
      }
      else if (numOfDecimal < 0)
      {
        numOfDecimal++;
      }
      if (str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1' && str[i] != '2'
          && str[i] != '3' && str[i] != '4' && str[i] != '5'
          && str[i] != '6' && str[i] != '7' && str[i] != '8'
          && str[i] != '9' )
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  bool isConstant(var str){
    if(isNumber(str))
      return true;
    else if(str[0]=='"' && str.length-1=='"')
      return true;
    else if(str[0]=='\'' && str.length-1=='\'')
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  bool isOperator(var ch)                   //check if the given character is a punctuator or not
  {
    if (ch == ':' || ch == ',' || ch == ';' ||  ch == '(' || ch == ')' ||
        ch == '[' || ch == ']' || ch == '{' || ch == '}'  || ch == '//' ||
        ch == '#' || ch == ',' ||ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' ||
        ch == '/' || ch == '>' || ch == '<' || ch == '=' || ch == '|' || ch == '&' ||
        ch == '%' ||ch == '\$')
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
  bool isIdentifier( var str)                       //check if the given identifier is valid or not
  {
    if (str[0] == '0' || str[0] == '1' || str[0] == '2' ||
        str[0] == '3' || str[0] == '4' || str[0] == '5' ||
        str[0] == '6' || str[0] == '7' || str[0] == '8' ||
        str[0] == '9' || isOperator(str[0]) == true)
    {
      return false;
    }                                   //if first character of string is a digit or a special character, identifier is not valid
    int i, len = str.length;/*The strlen() function returns the length of the null terminated byte string.
 It takes a null terminated byte string str as its argument and returns its length.The length does not include the null character.
 If there is no null character in the string, the behaviour of the function is undefined.*/
    if (len == 1)
    {
      return true;
    }                                       //if length is one, validation is already completed, hence return true
    else
    {
      for (i = 1; i < len; i++)                     //identifier cannot contain special characters
          {
        if (isOperator(str[i]) == true)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  bool isKeyword(String str){
    if (str == "if" || str == "else" || str == "while" || str == "do" || str == "break" || str == "continue" || str == "int"
        || str == "double" || str == "float" || str == "return" || str == "char" || str == "case" || str == "long" || str == "short"
        || str == "typedef" || str == "switch" || str == "unsigned" || str == "void" || str == "static" || str == "struct" || str == "sizeof"
        || str == "long" || str == "volatile" || str == "enum" || str == "const" || str == "union" || str == "extern" || str == "bool"
        || str == "alignas" || str == "alignof" || str == "and" || str == "and_eq" || str == "asm" || str == "atomic_cancel" || str == "atomic_commit"
        || str == "atomic_noexcept" || str == "auto" || str == "bitor" || str == "bitand" || str == "catch" || str == "char16_t" || str == "char32_t"
        ||str == "class" || str == "compl" || str == "concept" || str == "constexpr" || str == "const_cast" || str == "co_await" || str == "co_return"
        || str == "co_yield" || str == "bool" || str == "decltype" || str == "default" || str == "delete" || str == "double"  || str == "dynamic_cast"
        || str == "else" || str == "if" || str == "explicit" || str == "export" || str == "implements" || str == "false" || str == "float" || str == "for"
        || str == "friend" || str == "goto" || str == "import" || str == "inline" || str == "module" || str == "mutable" || str == "namespace" || str == "new"
        || str == "noexcept" || str == "not" || str == "not_eq" || str == "nullptr" || str == "operator" || str == "or" || str == "or_eq" || str == "private"
        || str == "protected" || str == "public" || str == "register" || str == "reinterpret_cast" || str == "requires" || str == "return" || str == "short"
        || str == "signed" || str == "static" || str == "static_assert" || str == "static_cast" || str == "synchronized" || str == "template"
        ||str == "this" || str == "thread_local")

      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  Token read_token(var token) {
    String s;
    var ch;
    for(int i=0; i<token.length; i++) {
      ch = token[i];
    }
    print(ch);
   // fdata >> ch;
    while(ch==' ') fdata.trim();
    if (token == '#' || token == ':' || token == ',' || token == ';' || token == '(' ||
        token == ')' || token == '[' || token == ']' || token == '{' || token == '}'
        || token == '//' || token == '#' || token == ',' || token == '+' || token == '-' ||
        token == '*' || token == '/' || token == '>' || token == '<' || token == '=' || token == '|' || token == '&'
        || token == '%' || token == '\$')
      print("Operator");
    else if (token == '<') {
      fdata.readAsBytes(ch);
      if (token == '=' || token == '>' || token == '<')
        print("Operator");
      else
        print("Error");
    }
    else if (token == '>') {
      fdata.readAsBytes(ch);
      if (token == '=' || token == '>')
         print("Operator");
      else
        print("Error");

    }
    else if (isCharacter(ch)) {
      s = ch; fdata.readAsBytes(ch);
      while (isNumber(ch)) {
        s += ch;
      }
      //fdata.putback(ch);
      print(isKeyword(s));
    }
    else {
      if (isNumber(ch)){
        s=ch; fdata.readAsBytes(ch);
        while(isAlphanumeric(ch)){
          s+=ch; fdata.readAsBytes(ch);
        }
        //fdata.putback(ch);
        print("Constant");
      }
      else print("Error");
    }
  }
  String Scan(var str) {
    Token strng = read_token(str);
    switch (strng) {
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("if");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("else");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("alignas");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("alignof");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("and");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("and_eq");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("asm");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("atomic_cancel");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("if");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("atomic_commit");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("atomic_noexcept");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("auto");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("bitand");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("bitor");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("bool");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("break");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("case");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("catch");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("char");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("char16_t");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("char32_t");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("class");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("compl");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("concept");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("const");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("constexpr");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("co_await");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("continue");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("const_cast");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("co_return");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("co_yield");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("decltype");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("default");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("delete");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("do");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("double");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("dynamic_cast");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("enum");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("explicit");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("export");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("extern");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("false");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("float");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("for");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("friend");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("goto");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("int");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("if");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("long");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("module");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("mutable");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("namespace");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("new");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("noexcept");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("not");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("not_eq");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("nullptr");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("operator");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("or");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("or_eq");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("private");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("protected");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("public");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("register");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("reinterpret_cast");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("requires");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("return");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("short");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("signed");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("sizeof");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("static");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("static_assert");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("static_cast");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("struct");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("switch");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("synchronized");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("template");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("this");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("thread_local");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("throw");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("typedef");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("try");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("true");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("typeid");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("typename");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("union");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("unsigned");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("using");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("virtual");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("wchar_t");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("volatile");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("void");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("while");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("xor");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Keyword:
        {
          print("xor_eq");
        }
        break;

      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print(":");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print(",");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print(";");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("(");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print(")");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("[");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("]");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("{");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("}");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("//");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("\$");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("%");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("&");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("|");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("=");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("<");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print(">");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("/");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("*");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("-");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("+");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Operator:
        {
          print("#");
        }
        break;
      case Token.Constant:
        {
          print(isNumber(strng.toString()));
        }
        break;
      case Token.Constant:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '"' && strng.toString().length - 1 == '"');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Constant:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '\'' && strng.toString().length - 1 == '\'');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '0');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '1');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '2');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '3');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '4');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '5');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '6');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '7');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '8');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '9');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Error:
        {
          print(isOperator(strng.toString()[0]) == true);
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'a' || strng.toString()[0] == 'A');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'b' || strng.toString()[0] == 'B');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'c' || strng.toString()[0] == 'C');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'd' || strng.toString()[0] == 'D');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'e' || strng.toString()[0] == 'E');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'f' || strng.toString()[0] == 'F');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'g' || strng.toString()[0] == 'G');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'h' || strng.toString()[0] == 'H');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'i' || strng.toString()[0] == 'I');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'j' || strng.toString()[0] == 'J');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'k' || strng.toString()[0] == 'K');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'l' || strng.toString()[0] == 'L');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'm' || strng.toString()[0] == 'M');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'n' || strng.toString()[0] == 'N');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'o' || strng.toString()[0] == 'O');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'p' || strng.toString()[0] == 'P');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'q' || strng.toString()[0] == 'Q');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'r' || strng.toString()[0] == 'R');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 's' || strng.toString()[0] == 'S');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 't' || strng.toString()[0] == 'T');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'v' || strng.toString()[0] == 'V');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'w' || strng.toString()[0] == 'W');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'x' || strng.toString()[0] == 'X');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'y' || strng.toString()[0] == 'Y');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == 'z' || strng.toString()[0] == 'Z');
        }
        break;
      case Token.Identifier:
        {
          print(strng.toString()[0] == '_');
        }
        break;
    }
  }
  Scan(fdata);
}
```

/*This is a code about lexical analysis that is is the first phase of a compiler. It takes the modified source code from language preprocessors that are written in the form of sentences. The lexical analyzer breaks these syntaxes into a series of tokens, by removing any whitespace or comments in the source code.

If the lexical analyzer finds a token invalid, it generates an error. The lexical analyzer works closely with the syntax analyzer. It reads character streams from the source code, checks for legal tokens, and passes the data to the syntax analyzer when it demands. The error is when I
run the code when I wrote the code in file to make a lexical analysis the compiler gave me the last item only and say its type not the whole items in the code in file data.txt why this error*/

Comment: There's potentially a lot of things wrong, but it's impossible to say what without knowing exactly what you expect. The code looks like it would generate some compiler errors. (For example, you have a lot of switch cases with the same value, what do you expect that to do?0 What are the errors you see? Can you fix them? If not, what about the error do you not understand?

Comment: I put the closed curly paranses in for(int i=0; i<token.length; i++) {
      ch = token[i];
    }before a function scan he split the code characters i want to split it as words and tell me its type

Comment: can you help me with this ,sir @lrn

Comment: and if i repeat the same case is it cause a problem?

Comment: You should look up what a switch statement does. It is meaningless to have the same case expression more than once.